# How to apply CSS to children of TR based on TD content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to hide a `<div>` or `<td>` inside the `<tr>` based on the content inside that `<tr>`.

If `Stackoverflow` is found inside a `<tr>`, hide `.buttons` from that `<tr>`.

This is what I've got so far.

```
<table class="sites">
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="name">Stackoverflow</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttons">
          buttons
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <class name="">Stackexchange</class>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttons">
        buttons
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

var t = $(".sites tr .name:contains('Stackoverflow')");
var d = t.parent('tr').children('.buttons');
d.css( "display", "none" );
```

I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3jk8e3b2/3/

Comment: What exactly is not working? SO is a great place to find answers but not open ended ones...

Comment: The .buttons <div> isn't hiding from the parent tr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your traverses are not going to appropriate levels.

`parent()` is only immediate parent element, `children()` are only immediate child nodes

In your case parent of `.name` is a `<td>` not `<tr>` and the buttons are not immediate children of `<tr>` either.

Use `closest()` or `parents()` to allow going up more than one level. Use `find()` to allow going deeper than `children()`

Try:

```
var t = $(".sites tr .name:contains('Stackoverflow')");
t.closest('tr').find('.buttons').hide();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3jk8e3b2/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: Will remember parents(), closest() & find().